# Is there a way to dynamically copy controls and their event handlers on a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

So here's the meat of what I want to accomplish: I have a rich textbox called txtNotes and two buttons to either save or delete.  When save is clicked, the text in the rich textbox will be saved to a database (not an issue), and a new rich textbox and buttons will appear below which will act the same as previously.  The delete button would remove those controls from the form and the info from the database.  The user should hypothetically be able to save and create an ulimited number of notes.

I have no idea if this is possible or if I'm thinking about this in completely the wrong way.  If you have any good solutions for me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Any control that's on your form got there by executing *code*.  If you didn't write that code yourself then you'll find it in the InitializeComponent() method in the designer.cs file.  Recreating a control is simple, just execute that same code again.  After properly disposing the original of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like it could get out of hand, and is extremely complex.

If you have a text box to allow the user to enter text and a button to save, why not use a listView or something similar, which could show the user what has been added to the database and then allow them to select items and delete them as they wish.

This control will be much more manageable and easily scrollable to take your "unlimited" number of entries.

You'll need to get a list of selected items in the listView to delete on deleteButton_Click event, then use this list to iteratively delete all of the items from your database.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: The problem with that is that the notes entered could be pretty extensive.  Also, it's not quite aesthetically what I'm going for.

Comment: I think you mean iteratively, not recursively.  At worst this operation would be done in a loop (iterative).  Would probably be better to do it as a single statement with an appropriate where clause though.

Answer (score 1):

Encapulating the RTB and Buttons in a UserControl seems like a good place to start.

Then you create a `TextSaveRequested(Object sender, TextEventArgs e)` event that is fired from the save button, and simply `Dispose()` the control when the delete is pressed (along with the related database activity, perhaps a TextDeleteRequested event).

Comment: I'll look into UserControls.  I've never used one before...  I'll let you know how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Controls.Add(CreateBox(0, 0));
    AutoScroll = true;
}

Panel CreateBox(int X, int Y)
{
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.Location = new Point(X, Y);
    panel.Size = new Size(100, 150);

    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
    panel.Controls.Add(rtb);

    Button b = new Button();
    b.Location = new Point(10, 100);
    b.Tag = rtb;
    b.Click += AllButtons_Click;
    panel.Controls.Add(b);

    return panel;
}

int i = 0;
void AllButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((RichTextBox)((sender as Button).Tag)).Text = "Clicked";
    i += 150;
    Controls.Add(CreateBox(0, i));
}
```

Although I'm getting some strange behavior from the AutoScroll.